# Mac SSH is looking in wrong location for key

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm trying to install some private github dependencies, but I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! fatal: cannot run ssh -i /home/user/id_rsa: No such file or directory
npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
```

My `id_rsa` file is located at `/Users/james/.ssh/id_rsa`. How do I fix this?

Also does anyone know why my key stopped working randomly? Yesterday, everything was fine. Today, I have to enter my github credentials to do anything.

EDIT: Found where I was defining the wrong location in my `.zshrc` file and fixed it:

```
export GIT_SSH='ssh -i /Users/james/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

However, I'm now getting this error:

```
fatal: cannot run ssh -i /Users/james/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork".
```

But if I copy that path directly from the error, I can confirm the file exists:

```
ls /Users/james/.ssh/id_rsa
/Users/james/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an issue with `ssh -i` on Mac. Apparently it doesn't work and just prints the help `ssh` help text.

All I had to do was remove the `export GIT_SSH` line from `.zshrc`. I'm still confused about how this mess happened in the first place because I only added that line to try to fix the original issue which is now apparently fixed.